# J# as an alternative to Java on Windows RT?

Tags: java, windows-runtime, clr, surface, j#

I have a source code written in Java that I would like to run on Windows RT / Surface 2. 
So far the tablet cannot run JVM. Is it possible to use J# to transform at least part of the code to run it under CRL (possibly with rewriting GUI part)? Will it be faster than start from zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. It requires some trickiness to use J# with .Net 4.0 and none of the tricks I've seen will work in a Windows Runtime app. Even if you could compile J# to the .Net Core framework, it probably wouldn't buy you much since you wouldn't have the java namespaces available.

It will probably be faster to convert from Java to C#, with the main difficulty being the differences in library code rather than language based. MSDN has a topic [Move from Android to WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj945421.aspx) that may help with that if you are familiar with Android programming.